# ActiveX component can't create object: 'jsShell.Ops' - but works via Editor

Tags: dll, vbscript, activex

I have following problem. I would like to use jsShell.dll ([Link to dll and description](http://www.jsware.net/jsware/scripts.php5#jsshl)) in my project. I use Win7 64 bit.

1. I downloaded dll and put it in C:\Windows\system\jsshell (files jsShell.dll and khook.dll)
2. I succesfully registered dll using c:\Windows\SysWOW64> regsvr32.exe c:\Windows\system\jsshell\jsShell.dll (it is not needed to register khook.dll)
3. Then I tried to run test file jsshell\jsShell DLL\demo scripts\window.vbs which is part of jsShell.zip by:

   a) double click to window.vbs and getting following error:

   **SCRIPT: C:\Users\joe\Downloads\jsshell\jsShell DLL\demoscripts\windows.vbs**

   **LINE: 6**

   **CHAR: 3**

   **ERROR: ActiveX component can't create object: 'jsShell.Ops'**

   **CODE: 800A01AD**

   **SOURCE: Microsoft VBScript runtime error**

   This is the line with error: `Set jsS = CreateObject("jsShell.Ops")`

   b) loading in WEB-ED Editor ([Link to WEB-EDD](http://www.jsware.net/jsware/webed.php5)) and running script over via editor, which works perfectly.

Could somebody please explain me, where is the difference between (a) and (b)? And what have to be done in order to run my script using (a) variant?

Thx a lot

Comment: You are running the 64-bit version of the VBS script executor when you click the VBS file.  It can't find nor use 32-bit components.

Comment: thx for your post, some idea how I could fix this?

Comment: Run it with c:\windows\syswow64\cscript.exe instead.

Comment: correct that was the problem, thx for helping me.